# VB.Net How to retrive info to form Text Boxes from SQL Server Table with Select Statement with Where clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This is my first day here in this site seeking for great help from any of you out there as great resource for beginner like me. I hope I will learn a lot from this site.

To the point: I am writing VB for desktop application with VB.NET with MS SQLServer 2014, currently installed on my machine.  My project name called “Employees Database”. I have created form with some text boxes where employees’ information would like to retrieve from the SQL Server table “tblEmployees”

I have already managed to fill the Listview with user details from sql server table “tblEmployees” with following code.

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class frmManageEmploye
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ANGD0542;Initial Catalog=ES&HDB;Integrated Security=True"}
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Private Sub filllistview()

        cn.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "SELECT EmpID, EmpName, Company, JobTitle, CraftClass, CraftCode, Department, Superintendent, Nationality, HireDate, ImagePath FROM tblEmployees"
        End With
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            With emplistview
                .Items.Add(dr.Item(0)) ' Emp Badge
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(1)) Then ' Emp Name
                        .Add(dr(1))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(2)) Then ' Company
                        .Add(dr(2))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(3)) Then ' Job Title
                        .Add(dr(3))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(4)) Then ' Craft Class
                        .Add(dr(4))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(5)) Then ' Craft Code
                        .Add(dr(5))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(6)) Then ' Department
                        .Add(dr(6))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(7)) Then ' Superintendent
                        .Add(dr(7))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(8)) Then ' Nationality
                        .Add(dr(8))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(9)) Then ' Hire Date
                        .Add(dr(9))
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(10)) Then 'Image Path
                        .Add(dr(10))
                    End If

                End With
            End With
        End While
        cn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmManageEmploye_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        filllistview()
    End Sub

    ...
End Class
```

Now my next challenge is to retrieve the user information to the text boxes I have in my form when I click the badge number of particular employee in the listview, along with Employee Picture from the Image Path that I have stored in SQL Server Table. I want to achieve this by select statement with where clause.

I am sure this most be old question someone had already raised in the past since I have just moved to VB.Net I am trying to learn this. Please help, Appreciated in advance!

Comment: Your first mistake is to use a ListView with a DB app.  Using a DataGridView, you can remove all that code and replace it with: `dgv.DataSource = myDataTable`.  The problem with the LV is that everything is string (and it is not really a Grid).

Comment: Hello Plutonix, Thank you for prompt reply, I kind of though of that using datagrid view but since I have decided to do with LV looking for solution.  But for sure, I will give try with DGV sometime. Thanks

Comment: So what's your question? You create the SELECT statement just like you have the one now, adding a WHERE clause that accepts a parameter for badge number, populate that parameter with the number you want to match, and execute the SQL statement just like you've done now. Then you use the data in the same exact way you're using the data now. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, May be I was not to cleaver enough to ask for help. However,  I wanted to achieve the view of employee picture on the form where EmpID is equal to to listview.selecteditems on click event.  I have stored the picture path into sql server table and the pictures are stored in share drive since attaching picture itself into database table is not a good idea.  After playing around with the code and a bit of extra hard work I kind of managed to achieve the result as I wanted.

I have managed to retrieve the information to the form text fields with the following code. Working fine as I click on the listview retrieving the employee’s information to the text fields

```
Private Sub emplistview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles emplistview.Click
    cn.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees where EmpID='" & emplistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text & "'"
    End With
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        txtEmpID.Text = dr.Item("EmpID")
        txtEmpName.Text = dr.Item("EmpName")
        txtcompany.Text = dr.Item("Company")
        txtjobtitle.Text = dr.Item("JobTitle")
        txtcraftclass.Text = dr.Item("CraftClass")
        txtNationality.Text = dr.Item("Nationality")
        txtcc.Text = dr.Item("CraftCode")
        txtdepartment.Text = dr.Item("Department")
        txtsuperintendent.Text = dr.Item("Superintendent")
        txthiredate.Text = dr.Item("HireDate")
        txtImagePath.Text = dr.Item("ImagePath")

    End While
    cn.Close()
    'ShowImage()
    getempimage()
End Sub
```

I have created another sub to get picture path and retrieve picture from the folder from share drive, and actual give me result as needed.  Please advise if the following code is effectively written or any greater ideas to achieve the goal

Public Sub getempimage()
        Try
            ' Initialize the connection to sql server
            Dim connString As String = "Data Source=ANGD0542;Initial Catalog=ES&HDB;Integrated Security=True;"
            Dim dbadaptor As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim dbdataset As New DataSet
            Dim dbconnection As SqlConnection
            dbconnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
            ' Open connection
            dbconnection.Open()
            'Select the employee picture from the table where employee badge is equal to listview selected items
            dbadaptor = New SqlDataAdapter("select ImagePath from tblEmployees WHERE EmpID='" & emplistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text & "'", dbconnection)
            dbadaptor.Fill(dbdataset)
            If (dbdataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 >= 0) Then
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dbdataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Show message if picture is not found or attached to table
            MessageBox.Show("Employee Picture not found")
        Finally

```
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'Close connect if connection state is still open
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank you